# Android - Multiple Threads causing app to crash

Tags: android, multithreading

Hi after everytime something is destroyed in my game i create a new object of an explosion animation done by the use of a thread class inside my surface view thread. After destroying multiple ships in a short period of time the app exits the activity. Why is this?

```
explosion ex = new explosion(x,y);
ex.start();
```

and

```
class explosion extends Thread implements Runnable{

    private long startTime;
    private int num = 0;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    public explosion(int mx, int my){
        x = mx;
        y = my;
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
    public void run(){
        while(num < 3){
            long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
            canvas.drawBitmap(explosions.get(num),x,y,null);
            if(millis - startTime > 50){
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                num++;
                Log.d("Explosion","Animate");
            }
        }
        Log.d("Explosion","End Thread");
    }
};
```

Comment: I believe editing the UI on another thread is a nono

Comment: It would help if you provided some log messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied from developer.android...

> Regardless of whether or not you use AsyncTask, always remember these
>   two rules about the single thread model:
>
> -Do not block the UI thread,
>
> -and Make sure that you access the AndroidUI toolkit only on the UI
>   thread.

I believe this line is causing you to crash...

```
canvas.drawBitmap(explosions.get(num),x,y,null);
```

This link details the steps to update UI on another thread:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Answer (score 0):

It smells like a design issue. Why would you run a thread for an animation ?
With due respect, I think you should run it in the current thread and use time based animation. You almost don't even need to change your code as it's already time based.

Comment: how could i do it without holding up the UI thread? i could use a handler but then i cant pass x and y to it

Comment: I assume your rendering part is called every 1/x th seconds ? Then just create your object and in your render part call the render part of your explosion object.